# Regular expression to find exact part in a string using php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

What should I use as a regex in order to get just the text between the double qoutes after url=

```
  <div class="anc-style" 
       url="c2l0ZT1odHRwJTNBJTJGJTJGZWFzeXJvdGF0b3IuY29tJTJGNjE1OTYlMkYmc2VjP TE1MjIzMyZsZW5nPWV4dGUmYWQ9MmM5ZTE5YjhiZWRiNzI1N2MxZGU2ODA2 Mjk0ZGZiYzcmYWQyPTAmYWQzPTAmYWQ0PTM=">
```

Comment: [**DO NOT PARSE XML WITH REGEX.**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/510036). Seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You regexp would be

```
$string = "your string here";

echo urldecode(base64_decode(preg_replace('/^.*url="(.*)".*$/', '$1', $string)));
```

If that's the url you want, I added base64_decode, and then urldecode since the result contained urlencoded characters.

Also I stongly suggest you learn regex basics if you'll be needing other search and replace!

Comment: my point was how to get the exact url(c2l0ZT1odHRwJTNBJTJGJTJGZWFzeXJvdGF0b3IuY29tJTJGNjE1OTYlMkYmc2VjP TE1MjIzMyZsZW5nPWV4dGUmYWQ9MmM5ZTE5YjhiZWRiNzI1N2MxZGU2ODA2 Mjk0ZGZiYzcmYWQyPTAmYWQzPTAmYWQ0PTM=) from html document that contains this url